Mathematically Scaling a Simulation
Suppose I have the following parameters in a (M/M/K) Queue:

Arrival rate (λ) = 300
Number of servers (c) = 2
Service rate per server (μ) = 5.1

This is taking a long time in my software since the individual arrivals are actually being simulated.
I was wondering if it mathematically makes sense to scale initial parameters down, simulate to get a faster simulation - and then scale the results back up?
E.g. Scaled system (divide by 100):

Arrival rate (λ') = 3
Number of servers (c') = 2 (unchanged)
Service rate per server (μ') = 0.051

From a mathematical perspective, does this make sense?

Yes, you change the time scale. This is similar to solar system simulations, where using days and astronomical units makes for easier numbers in a simulation  of the inner system (position and speed in close magnitudes) than the usual seconds and meters that are common in physics simulations.

Mathematically, this makes sense, but something is wrong if it actually helps your simulation.
In an M/M/whatever queue, both inter-arrival times and service times are exponentially distributed, and the rate of an exponential distribution is an inverse scale parameter: if $\mathbf X \sim \text{Exponential}(\alpha)$, then $k\mathbf X \sim \text{Exponential}(\alpha/k)$. As a result, you can already convert between the two models as follows:

Suppose you simulate an M/M/2 queue with arrival rate $\lambda = 300$ and service rate $\mu = 5.1$ for some time, then multiply the time at which every event occurs by $100$. (For example, if the simulation begins by a job arriving at time $0.0123$ and being processed at time $0.0456$, you would change the arrival time to $1.23$ and the time when it is processed to $4.56$.) The result is a simulation of an M/M/2 queue with arrival rate $\lambda' = 3$ and service rate $\mu' = 0.051$.
Conversely, if you simulate the M/M/2 queue with arrival rate $\lambda' = 3$ and service rate $\mu' = 0.051$, and then divide the time at which every event occurs by $100$, you'll get a simulation of the M/M/2 queue with arrival rate $\lambda=300$ and service rate $\mu = 5.1$.

Scaling the times of all events will not change time-independent parameters, like the fraction of time that a system is idle (though in this case, because the load is so high, we expect that the size of the queue will just keep growing with time in both systems, which makes most time-independent parameters irrelevant). It will scale all time-dependent parameters accordingly; for example, if you want to measure the average time until the queue grows to $100$ jobs, by repeated runs of the simulation, that average time will be off by a factor of $100$ between the two models.
(You can also think of the difference as being a difference in units: imagine that we're simulating the exact same system, except in one case our units of time are seconds, and in the other case, our units of time are centiseconds.)

The fact that you're hoping to benefit from scaling the model, though, suggests that there's some difference in the way you're interpreting the simulations. Because the two models are equivalent, this suggests that you're paying for the benefit somehow, and just not realize it. I don't know exactly how you're hoping to benefit, but here are two possibilities where the two queues might end up simulated differently, and why this doesn't help:
Method of generating random variables.
There are two ways you might simulate such a queue. You could actually take samples from the Exponential distribution (e.g. by taking the log of a uniform random variable) to determine inter-arrival and service times, in which case the two simulations will be roughly equivalent.
You might also take what is called a $\delta$-step approximation: pick a very small $\delta > 0$, and approximate your arrival times by saying that there is a $\lambda \delta$ probability of an arrival every $\delta$ time units. (Service times are modeled analogously.) The quality of this approximation increases as $\delta$ approaches $0$.
The thing to realize is that because the effect of $\delta$ on the simulation is time-dependent, the quality of the approximation for a fixed $\delta$ will be different between the two simulations. If you want equally good approximations of the two simulations, you should take $\delta$ to be $100$ times smaller in the queue with $\lambda' = 3$ and $\mu' = 0.051$. (And if you don't, you might be able to simulate the second queue more easily, but that's because you made your approximation worse and didn't notice.)
How long do you run the simulation?
Suppose the way you try to measure some property of the system is by saying "let's approximate the steady state by looking at the simulation after $1000$ time units, doing this for many runs of the simulation, and averaging". There's lots of variants of how you might do this, but broadly speaking this is reasonable.
Again, because we said the magic words "time units", this will produce very different results between the two simulations! It will be much easier to run the slowed-down queue with $\lambda' = 3$ and $\mu' = 0.051$ for $1000$ time units, but the parameters you measure will be equivalent to the parameters of the original queue after only $10$ time units. So if you're hoping for convergence to a steady state, you will have to run the slowed-down queue for $100$ times as long to get the same amount of convergence.
(In this particular case, neither queue will converge to a steady state; we'll just accumulate more and more jobs in the queue. But the number of waiting jobs will grow linearly with time, so in the fast model, there will be roughly $100\times$ as many jobs in the system after $1000$ time units.)
